# Eclipse Scrapbook > Set Imports... not saving

Tags: java, eclipse

1. Create a new Eclipse project.
2. Create a new .jpage file in that project.
3. Right click in the editor and choose Set imports...
4. Add type...

At this point the dialog matches my import type and it shows up correctly in the import list.

4. Click OK on the dialog.
5. Try to execute my Scrapbook code.

At this point I get errors "cannot be resolved to a type", etc., as though the imports are not imported.

6. Re-open the dialog.

At this point no imports are showing in the dialog, as though my imports didn't save at all.

There are no errors showing in the Error Log view in Eclipse.

How can I add imports for the Scrapbook in Eclipse? Where is this supposed to save?

Comment: same for me unfortunately :( . Seems to be a bug of relatively recent eclipse or whatever software component is responsible for the scrapbook. At least this didn't happen in earlier versions. Maybe you should add your eclipse version to the description of this question ... Mine is 2022-12 (4.26.0) . Sorry to not be of any help.

Comment: This is also happening on Eclipse STSVersion: 4.18.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 202305021758
Revision: 85103b61dc8f2777b48c9a1ff1e55c7057f156f2